Export copy-paste-able HTML from keynote
When I export a Keynote presentation to HTML, none of the text or code is copy/paste-able (I think it is rendered to an HTML5 canvas?)... Is there a way to export so that it behaves like normal HTML (highlighted-able, copy/paste-able, clickable-links, translatable, etc.) ?
The big picture: I need to output Keynote presentations in some way that students can copy/paste code from the presentation, and also translate slides if needed, preferably without having to download the entire thing, and upload it to a translation 'service'.
I'm current using Keynote 14.2, thanks

What if you export it to PDF?

Export via pdf is ok, but you lose animations, video, etc., plus its less easy to translate: you have to download the pdf, then upload it to a translation service. Seems there should be a way to export as standard html5, no ?
